# 'unsigned short var' vs 'unsigned char var [2]' in C++

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

In C++, I can declare a variable as either an unsigned short or an unsigned char (with 2 bytes) as shown below. However, is there any differences?

```
unsigned short p;
unsigned char q[2];
```

Comment: One thing to think about is that `short` is not guaranteed to be two bytes or 16 bits.

Comment: Any differences? Aside from the fact that they are totally different types? (array vs not an array, short vs char).

Comment: Also, *why* do you ask? What is the problem you're *really* trying to solve?

Comment: This is a very bad question. Please consult some basic materials about C++ before asking questions.

Comment: Endianess?  A short is a multibyte quantity, and may be represented on some systems as Most Significant Byte (MSB) first or Least Significant Byte first (LSB).  An array has no significant byte ordering.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have shamelessly included your point in the answer. :)

Comment: After reading all of your responses above, I started to realize perhaps it is safe to say the obvious difference is the former is a two bytes of integer while the later is a 2 bytes of chars.

Comment: Yes. Simply try using these both to do things with numbers within the range of the `unsigned short` and see which one you find easiest. The difference will then be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Differences:

- Types are different. C++ is a strongly typed language and the compiler enforces the type checking.
- Size might differ. We know that there is [no padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676414/1460794) between the elements, but these two variables might not have the same amount of memory,
  because the size of the `short` is [platform dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/1460794).
- Endianess. A short is a multibyte quantity, and may be represented on some systems as Most Significant Byte (MSB) first or Least Significant Byte first (LSB). The `char` array has no significant byte ordering.
- Alignment. The `char` array may not be allocated on one of the same [alignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment) boundaries as a `short`.
- Aliasing. The `short` may be casted to a `char` array so that it may be evaluated as an array of bytes, but the reverse [is not allowed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

Comment: 2 more: Alignment and pointer aliasing. This is why taking a pointer to a char array and casting it to pointer-to-whatever is very very forbidden.